# Constructing an isomorphism from the set of polynomials with real coefficients to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \mapsto f(0)$, i.e $$a_nx^n + ... + a_1x + a_0 \mapsto a_0$$ then by the fundamental homomorphism theorem, we have that $$\mathbb{R}[x]/x\mathbb{R}[x] \cong \mathbb{R}$$ since $ker\phi = x\mathbb{R}[x]$.

I understand the fundamental homomorphism theorem, but I can not see how to construct such an isomorphism between these two rings, hence the idea here seems unintuitive to me.

How should I construct one?

Comment: What is wrong with $f(x)+x\Bbb R[x]\mapsto f(0)$?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean exactly, is that a suggestion for an isomorphism? Is that map injective?

Comment: This map is an isomorphism by one of the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: Let $I$ be a two-sided ideal of a ring $R$. If $\alpha \colon R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism such that $I \subseteq \ker \alpha$, then the assignment $r+I \mapsto \alpha(r)$ defines a ring homomorphism $\widetilde \alpha \colon R/I \to S$ with $\ker \widetilde \alpha = (\ker \alpha)/I$ and $\operatorname{im} \widetilde \alpha = \operatorname{im} \alpha$. In particular, if $\ker \alpha = I$, then $\widetilde \alpha$ is injective (since $\ker \widetilde \alpha$ is trivial); and if $\operatorname{im} \alpha = S$, then $\widetilde \alpha$ is surjective.

Comment: I think your problem here is less in figuring out the isomorphism, which as azif00 points out, is explicitly defined in that homomorphism theorem. Your problem is more in understanding what $\Bbb R[x]/x\Bbb R[x]$ is. Two polynomials are equivalent if they differ by a polynomial with no constant term. Which will be the case if and only if the two polynomials have the same constant term. Thus each equivalence clase in $\Bbb R[x]/x\Bbb R[x]$ consists of all polynomials have a particular constant term. The isomorphism identifies the equivalence class with its shared constant term.